# jQuery mobile Datebox CSS not loading properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, datebox

I have a simple two page website developed using jQuery mobile framework. I had the need to use Datebox plugin for selection of times. Both pages of my website are in the same .php file separated by divs with `data-role="page"` appropriately.

My only problem is that if the datebox exists in the first page of the webpage, it loads properly, but in any other page, its icons are messed up.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>Home</title> 
    <meta charset="utf-8">  
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">  

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://cdn.jtsage.com/jtsage-datebox/4.1.1/jtsage-datebox-4.1.1.jqm.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="http://cdn.jtsage.com/jtsage-datebox/4.1.1/jtsage-datebox-4.1.1.jqm.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


</head> 
<body> 

    <div data-role="page" id="index">
        <header data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h1>Home</h1>
        </header>

        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <div class="ui-field-contain">
                <label for="datebox">Time (seconds)</label>
                <input type="text" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode":"calbox"}'>
            </div>
        </div>

        <footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" style="text-align:center;" class="ui-body-a">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#index" data-direction="reverse" class="ui-btn ui-icon-plus ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#onoff" class="ui-btn ui-icon-plus ui-btn-icon-left">ON/OFF</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#timer" class="ui-btn ui-icon-plus ui-btn-icon-left">Timer</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-icon-plus ui-btn-icon-left">Scheduler</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </footer> 
    </div>

    <div data-role="page" id="onoff">
        <header data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h1>ONOFF</h1>
        </header>

        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">

            <div class="ui-field-contain">
                <label for="datebox">Time (seconds)</label>
                <input type="text" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode":"calbox"}'>
            </div>
        </div>

        <footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" style="text-align:center;" class="ui-body-a">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#index" class="ui-btn ui-icon-plus ui-btn-icon-left">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#onoff" data-direction="reverse" class="ui-btn ui-icon-plus ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">ON/OFF</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#timer" class="ui-btn ui-icon-plus ui-btn-icon-left">Timer</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-icon-plus ui-btn-icon-left">Scheduler</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </footer>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

The following images show the issue. On page load, the first div with `page-role="page"` and `id="index"` is loaded and the datebox icon works as intended:

[image: Home Page]

But if I navigate to the second page using the footer navbar ON/OFF tab, I get this weird icon placement:

[image: ON/OFF page]

Please help me figure out what is going wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user3889963 hit the nail on the head.

Download the source files for JQM for Datebox and then call them directly within your head.

```
<script src="../jtsage-datebox.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="../jtsage-datebox.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

This previous question shows there is a problem with using the plugin via the CDN [Jquery Mobile DateBox plugin only working when linked directly to page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708839/jquery-mobile-datebox-plugin-only-working-when-linked-directly-to-page)

Here is it working with the files installed directly.
[image]

Comment: This answer added for reference only.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I'm not sure why this is but using local files instead of the CDN links in the head enabled me to use the datebox plugin across pages. The files were generated using the download builder found here:

http://dev.jtsage.com/DateBox/builder/

Answer (score 0):

Unique Naming is the problem.

Within both pages you are calling the datebox item by the same name, so only the first one gets styled correctly.

Just rename the second page as datebox2 this should fix the problem. As the label for searches for the first unique ID of "datebox" and styles that one.

```
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <div class="ui-field-contain">
                <label for="datebox2">Time (seconds)</label>
                <input type="text" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode":"calbox"}'>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: That doesn't seem like the issue. I still get the same output after changing the label for=datebox2

Comment: @user3889963 This answer is wrong, but I would recommend unique naming for the Datebox field as shortly you will come across issues when trying to target the values of the datebox with in JQM.