# $(select).selectmenu('open') doesn't work if page is loaded using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I have a button that shows a dropdown menu when clicked. This code works on pages that are loaded with `data-ajax="false"`:

```js
$('#btnMainMenu').live('click', function() {
  $('#dpMainMenu').selectmenu('open');
});
```

But there are some anchors on the website where `data-ajax="true"`, so whenever the users load those pages - the codes above doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated since jQuery 1.7, use `.on()` instead: [.live() docs](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449402/jquery-mobile-mobile-changepage-not-loading-external-js-files/7449731#7449731. Where have you put the code that doesn't work via AJAX, is it in the `<head>` of a document?

Comment: @Jasper, i placed the above code in <head> section. I also tried to put $('#dpMainMenu').selectmenu('open'); directly on anchor's onclick event but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Pages that are loaded with `data-ajax="true"` only load a specific part of the pages (which is the default behaviour for jQuery Mobile). Namely everything between `<div data-role="page">...</div>`. Does your code work even though pages are loaded this way?

References: [Linking Pages](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/pages/page-links.html)

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and my solution was to include the code bellow in the body of the page that is being loaded via Ajax (I put it just bellow the form).

```
<script>
    $('document').read(function () {
        $("#form-id").trigger("refresh", true); 
    });
</script>
```

With this, when the page is ready Jquery recreates the form where the selectmenu is and so all behaviours are back again.